# Send Push Notification from Cloud Function in iOS

Tags: javascript, json, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm able to print and send test notification from firebase console with the token retrieved from firestore. But somehow I get Error Sending Notification: INTERNAL when I'm trying to send push notification via JavaScript

This is my JavaScript code

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp();

const messaging = admin.messaging();
exports.getUserData = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const clientUid = data.clientUid;

  try {
    const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(clientUid).get();
    const userData = snapshot.data();
    const token = userData.token;
    const tokenString = JSON.stringify(token);
    console.log(`Token String: ${tokenString}`);
    console.log(`User data: ${JSON.stringify(userData)}`);
    return userData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error retrieving user data: ${error}`);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Error retrieving user data.');
  }
});

exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const token = data.token;

  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'New Notification',
      body: 'You have a new notification!'
    }
  };

  try {
      const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload, {
        contentAvailable: true,
        priority: 'high'
      });
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
    return { message: 'Push notification sent successfully!' };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending push notification:', error);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Error sending push notification');
  }
});
```

and the following is my code in SwiftUI

```
import SwiftUI
import JavaScriptCore
import Firebase
import StoreKit
import FirebaseFunctions

class JSNotification: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var token = ""
    
    func sendNotificationFromSwift(clientUid: String) {
        
        let context = JSContext()!
        
        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "js", inDirectory: "functions") {
            do {
                let content = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath)
                context.evaluateScript(content)
                let functions = Functions.functions()
                let sendNotification = functions.httpsCallable("sendNotification")

                Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(clientUid).getDocument { snapshot, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    } else {
                        if let data = snapshot?.data() {
                            self.token = data["token"] as? String ?? ""
                            print(self.token)
                            sendNotification.call(["token": self.token]) { result, error in
                                if let error = error {
                                    print("Error Sending Notification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    return
                                } else {
                                    print("Push Notification Is Sent")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error Reading JS File.")
            }
        } else {
            print("No Path Found.")
        }
    }
}
```

The sendNotificationFromSwift is called as follow

```
import Firebase
import SwiftUI

struct TestJSView: View {
    
    @StateObject var jsNotification = JSNotification()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            jsNotification.sendNotificationFromSwift(clientUid: "A_Valid_Uid")
        } label: {
            Text("Test JS Notification")
        }
    }
}
```

The JavaScript function has been successfully deployed too.
Can anyone please let me know what went wrong? Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you look at the log for the function on Google cloud “internal” is usually more defined

Comment: I ran the firebase functions:log command in terminal and found this error
Error sending push notification: FirebaseMessagingError: An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers.
Yea I solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: If you add an answer with your detailed steps for diagnosing and solving you can mark it as an answer and help someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved the issue.
I ran this command in my terminal:

firebase functions:log

that gives me the details of the error "INTERNAL" which in my case is "sendNotification: Error sending push notification: FirebaseMessagingError: An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions." generated from this function above

```
func sendNotificationFromSwift(clientUid: String) {
        
        let context = JSContext()!
        
        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "js", inDirectory: "functions") {
            do {
                let content = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath)
                context.evaluateScript(content)
                let functions = Functions.functions()
                let sendNotification = functions.httpsCallable("sendNotification")

                Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(clientUid).getDocument { snapshot, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    } else {
                        if let data = snapshot?.data() {
                            self.token = data["token"] as? String ?? ""
                            print(self.token)
                            sendNotification.call(["token": self.token]) { result, error in
                                if let error = error {
    //Error generated from here
                                    print("Error Sending Notification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    return
                                } else {
                                    print("Push Notification Is Sent")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error Reading JS File.")
            }
        } else {
            print("No Path Found.")
        }
    }
```

And the solution can be found [here](https://dev.to/codarbind/an-error-occurred-when-trying-to-authenticate-to-the-fcm-servers-2g3).